# Tangent space of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

For a manifold, $M$, at point $p$ we have a set of real-valued smooth function, $C^\infty_p(M)$ passing through $p$. To prove the tangent space at point $p$ we assume that we have map $C^\infty_p(M) =\{f:M \to R\}$, $\gamma:R \to M$ and try to find $\frac{df(\gamma(\tau))}{d\tau}$. The map $\gamma$ takes a point $\tau$ from one-dimensional curve and give a point on the manifold along the curve $\gamma(\tau)$ where $\gamma(\tau=0) = p$. But I can not understand what kind of mapping the function $f$ does? Is it take any one of the curve passing through $p$ and give a real value? Then what direactional derivative $\frac{df(\gamma(\tau))}{d(\tau)}$ mean in that case? Is it the rate of change of the curve when I change the parameter $\tau$ slightly?

Comment: The symbol $C^\infty(M)$ means functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$, while you probably meant $\mathbb{R} \to M$ (you can use $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ for this). For $f$ and $\gamma$ as described, the composition $f \circ \gamma$ doesn't make sense; it would if $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ instead. Your problems probably start somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks I edited this.

Comment: Hm, it makes more sense now. But now the point $p$ doesn't have any role in $C_p^\infty(M)$. It should also be written that the derivative $\frac{df(\gamma(\tau))}{d\tau}(0)$ is evaluated at $0$ (since $\gamma(0) = p$). 
Up to this notational remark, you're exactly right that this is _the rate of change of the curve when you change the parameter $\tau$ slightly_. But to get an accurate formal answer, you need to add a bit about the manifold $M$. Is it a subset (submanifold) of $\mathbb{R}^d$? Is it an abstract manifold?

Comment: I am thinking it as regular manifold. Also can you please explain me what $C^\infty_p(M) =\{f:M \to R\}$ this mapping mean since I am not so clear about this?

Comment: I don't think _regular manifold_ answers my question. As for $C_p^\infty(M)$, I don't think you need $p$ there. Also, $C^\infty(M)$ is not a mapping, but the family of all mappings from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$. And then a composition of $\gamma \colon \mathbb{R} \to M$ with $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a quite straightforward thing.

Comment: It seems that you are quite confused with the definition. $C^\infty_p(M)$ usually denote the space of germ of smooth functions at $p$, while tangent vector can be identified as derivation on $C^\infty_p(M)$. On the other hand, tangent vector can also be identified as mapping $\gamma : I \to M$ from an interval (that is, a curve)